# Combining the values in two dictionaries into a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In python if I have two dictionaries, specifically Counter objects that look like so

```
c1 = Counter({'item1': 4, 'item2':2, 'item3': 5, 'item4': 3})
c2 = Counter({'item1': 6, 'item2':2, 'item3': 1, 'item5': 9})
```

Can I combine these dictionaries so that the results is a dictionary of lists, as follows:

```
c3 = {'item1': [4,6], 'item2':[2,2], 'item3': [5,1], 'item4': [3], 'item5': [9]}
```

where each value is a list of all the values of the preceding dictionaries from the appropriate key, and where there are no matching keys between the two original dictionaries, a new kew is added that contains a one element list.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter({'item1': 4, 'item2':2, 'item3': 5, 'item4': 3})
c2 = Counter({'item1': 6, 'item2':2, 'item3': 1, 'item5': 9})
c3 = {}
for c in (c1, c2):
    for k,v in c.iteritems():
        c3.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

`c3` is now: `{'item1': [4, 6], 'item2': [2, 2], 'item3': [5, 1], 'item4': [3], 'item5': [9]}`

Answer (score 2):

Or with a list comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
c1 = Counter({'item1': 4, 'item2':2, 'item3': 5, 'item4': 3})
c2 = Counter({'item1': 6, 'item2':2, 'item3': 1, 'item5': 9})
merged = {}
for k in set().union(c1, c2):
    merged[k] = [d[k] for d in [c1, c2] if k in d]

>>> merged
{'item2': [2, 2], 'item3': [5, 1], 'item1': [4, 6], 'item4': [3], 'item5': [9]}
```

### Explanation

1. Throw all keys that exist into an anonymous set. (It's a set => no duplicate keys)
2. For every key, do 3.
3. For every dictionary d in the list of dictionaries `[c1, c2]`

   - Check whether the currently being processed key `k` exists

     - If true: include the expression `d[k]` in the resulting list
     - If not: proceed with next iteration

[Here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is a detailed introduction to list comprehension with many examples.

Comment: I tried this but I got a `merged[k] = [d[k] for d in [c1, c2] if k in d] TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` error. I don't understand what it's doing to be able to fix it. I haven't really gotten then hang of list comprehensions yet.

Comment: @DavyKavanagh My mistake, merged has to be a dictionary of course.

Comment: @DavyKavanagh I have added an explanation. -- Does the OP get notified if an answer to his question is edited?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, defaultdict
>>> c1 = Counter({'item1': 4, 'item2':2, 'item3': 5, 'item4': 3})
>>> c2 = Counter({'item1': 6, 'item2':2, 'item3': 1, 'item5': 9})
>>> c3 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for c in c1, c2:
...     for k, v in c.items():
...         c3[k].append(v)
... 
>>> c3
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'item2': [2, 2], 'item3': [5, 1], 'item1': [4, 6],
'item4': [3], 'item5': [9]})
```